# Window decorations disappeared

Tags: 10.10, compiz, metacity, window-management

I was trying to solve NetworkManager icon disappearence, and following some tips I executed this command:

```
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
```

Not only it didn't worked, but windows decorations disappeared as well (title, close button, etc) and who knows what else that I didn't noticed.

I found the [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5998/window-decorations-disappearedBlockquote) about this issue, but I want a permanent solution... running `metacity --replace` fixes the issue until next login, and adding it to the startup commands sound lame. I want to undo the damage, not put duct tape over it.

Note: Ubuntu 10.10 with compiz

---

New (partial) solution:

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/panel
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

I don't know exactly what is being done here (removing a folder, killing a process), but my decorations and icons are back. It removed additional icons I had set on the panel, and may have disabled some compiz settings (I'm not sure about that, it could be earlier side effect of my various 'fixes'), nothing serious.

Unfortunately, on the next full restart, decorations missing again.

Comment: I think you mean compiz --replace

Comment: No, it's metacity --replace indeed, I read it in the question I linked above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reinstalling gnome panels

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-panel`

And for your Network manager applet problem if it isn't fixed yet, edit network manager conf

`sudoedit /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf`

and change `managed=false` to `managed=true` and then save the file. In the terminal type `killall nm-system-settings` and restart.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I'll try it tonight. And further thanks for the extra fix for NetworkManager... it still vanishes sometimes. Hope I can make it stick once and for all!

Comment: Thanks for your reinstall tip. It worked, but it seems that it made my shutdown icon disappear =(

Comment: Did you try adding Indicator applet Sessions from add to panel ?

Comment: I didn't knew of it, thanks for the info. But anyway, my decorations are missing again (see question). Man, I'm getting pissed! Can't I fix this once and for all???

Comment: Final try 

How to reset ubuntu/Gnome settings to default without loosing any data or reinstalling. Try this link



http://open-help.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-rest-ubuntugnome-settings-to.html

Comment: Next time it happens, I'll try it. I see it will wipe out all my configs, but still, if it fixes this I won't have to do it again.

Comment: Ok, it didn't worked permanently, and it haven't happened since I upgraded to Natty, so I'm finishing this.